# "Index sitecore_suggested_test_index was not found" exception on CD server

Tags: indexing

I have suddenly found a significant number of those error messages on the Sitecore log of my CD server; my understanding is that this particular index does/should not exist in production, which is why those errors do not appear in my Dev an CM environments.

**Question**

How do I tell Sitecore to stop trying to rebuild a specific index *in production only*?

Comment: Have you made any configuration changes lately? This type of thing (where an index was previously excluded and suddenly exists) is often because a patch config was added that was intended to patch a setting on this index but ended up adding it (because it was excluded somewhere else).

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I would simply like to know how to control which indexes are rebuilt and in which envirornment.

Comment: They are controlled by the configuration files in `App_Config` and how they are updated/rebuilt is controlled by the indexing strategies: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/index-update-strategies.html. I would recommend having a look at `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` for that environment and seeing how they are configured currently.

Comment: The link you posted helped me to find the root cause of the problem - indeed, the configuration element that removed sitec_suggested_test_index from web was missing; re-introducing it fixed the problem.

If you post your comment as an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexing strategies are controlled by the configuration files in `App_Config` and how they are updated/rebuilt is controlled by the indexing strategies:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/index-update-strategies.html

I would recommend having a look at `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` for that environment and seeing how they are configured currently.